# XSL error "An attribute whose value must be a QName had the value '300x300'"

Tags: xml, xslt

I get this error when trying to name an attribute with the image dimensions (300x300, 420x420, etc).

When I generate the same elements beginning with a letter, everything goes allright.

Here's what I got:

```
<xsl:for-each select="additionalImages/image">
    <xsl:if test="additional_image_dimensions != ''">
        <xsl:element name="{additional_image_dimensions}">
            <xsl:value-of select="additionalUrl"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I already tried to concatenate nothing to the string `{concat('', additional_image_dimensions)}`

Here's what I want:

`<300x300>url</300x300>`

Ps.: When I try to put a letter on the beginning, it works:

```
<x30x30>url</x30x30>
<x300x300>url</x300x300>
```

How can I generate a dynamic element named like `<300x300>url</300x300>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I generate a dynamic element named like
>   `<300x300>url</300x300>`?

You can't: an element name cannot begin with a digit:
http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar